# How can I get Bengali Sign Anusvara, Anji, and Uu in XeLaTeX?

Tags: unicode

I'm deciphering ancient Indian manuscript by using XeLaTeX (Version 4.31) based on MacOS. I want to type "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982), "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980), and "Bengali Vowel Sign Uu" ূ (U+09C2). Fortunately, Arun Debray's setting WORKS for me. Thank you! ([How can I use Bengali script in an English document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285507/how-can-i-use-bengali-script-in-an-english-document))

So I have tried to slightly modify Arun Debray's file to show "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982) as follows.

```latex
\documentclass[preview, margin=0.5cm]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}

% Replace this with whatever font you're using
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}

\title{\textbengali{ইংরেজি} and Bengali}

\usepackage{newunicodechar} % <=== Added 

\newunicodechar{^^^^25bc}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"25BC}}} % <=== Added
\newunicodechar{^^^^0982}{{\symbolfont\symbol{"0982}}} % <=== Added 

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}  % <=== Added
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}  % <=== Added

\begin{document}

\maketitle

First English, \textbengali{তারপর বাংলা} 
{^^^^25bc} 
{^^^^0982}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the result was not successful. "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982) does not appear. Even the existing Bengali letter is damaged by adding the lines. Comparatively, it presents a black triangle (U+0982) without any problem. Could you give me some advice to modify this file to get those three letters? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+0982 is a Bengali character:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}

% Replace this with whatever font you're using
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Bangla MN}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\newfontfamily\symbolfont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\newunicodechar{▼}{{\symbolfont▼}}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbengali{ইংরেজি} and Bengali}
\author{Woonsaan Seok}

\maketitle

First English, \textbengali{তারপর বাংলা} 

▼

\textbengali{^^^^0982}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ergreg Thank you very much for your elaborated MWE. I found a rule of "mutual exclusion" in Bengali fonts. Group A (Bangla MN, Noto Sans Bengali and so on) support not "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982) but "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980). On the other hand, group B (FreeSerif) only supports "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982), not "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980). Then, I wish to use group B by adding "\newfontfamily\bengalifont[/Users/XXXX/Library/Fonts/]{FreeSerif.ttf}" to the preamble. How can I obtain "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980) by using group A only in a portion of a work?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, *anji* is rarely implemented in the fonts.

I found only three fonts out of 98+ with Bengali unicode block that have it:

[image: anji]

As a workaround, if your main font is FreeSerif, say, you can make an `\anji` macro using the Noto Serif Bengali font, say. Both are serif, so they mix well.

[image: anji from another font]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}[Script=Bengali,Colour=blue]

\newfontface\anjifont{Noto Serif Bengali}[Colour=red]

\newcommand\anji{{\anjifont ঀ}}

\begin{document}

\anji\  সৌরজগৎ বলতে সূর্য এবং এর সাথে মহাকর্ষীয়ভাবে আবদ্ধ সকল জ্যোতির্বৈজ্ঞানিক বস্তুকে বোঝায়। %from Wikipedia

\end{document}
```

Size can be adjusted, if desired.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much Cicada! This information is very useful because the Sanskrit manuscript which I deal with has lots of these special signs. Thank you very much again for your invaluable information!

Answer (score 0):

`newunicodechar` seems to cause the problem you report. Try avoiding to use it.
With respect to Anji, it works only with some fonts. Whatever reason it be, it works with Noto Serif Bengali (https://www.google.com/get/noto/#serif-beng), but not Akaash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborated MWE. I found a rule of "mutual exclusion" in Bengali fonts. Group A (Bangla MN, Noto Sans Bengali and so on) support not "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982) but "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980). On the other hand, group B (FreeSerif) only supports "Benalgi Sign Anusvara" ং (U+0982), not "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980). Then, I wish to use group B by adding "\newfontfamily\bengalifont[/Users/XXXX/Library/Fonts/]{FreeSerif.ttf}" to the preamble. How can I obtain "Bengali Anji" ঀ (U+0980) by using group A only in a portion of a work?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45545/unicode-in-xetex-with-automatic-font-substitution

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind advice. I'll visit the page as soon as possible.